# How start a animation in a certain time?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a CABasicAnimation involving multiple shapes that shows a transition between two different navigations. It's essentially a morph with an x duration.
However, there are a couple of requirements that I don't know how to deal with (and my googlefu isn't helping)

- I need to be able to show an arbitrary point of the animation. For instance, if I'm mid-swipe between two views I need to be able to show the animation at 50%.
- I need to be able to start the animation at an arbitrary point. In the previous case, if I'm mid-swipe and release the view I need to be able to complete the animation from 50% to 100%.
  I gave it a shot with timeSincePause (code) but I can't get anywhere with the animation.

As an aid I have these two methods,

If the method of **Resume** an animation is an implicit way of continuing the same from a certain point with difference that is continuous from a time **X** which is defined by the **pause** method, how can I get it to NOT be the pause method that defines Continue ***beginTime*** if not already determined

```
@IBAction func tapPause() {
    let pausetime = shape.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil)
    shape.speed = 0.0
    shape.timeOffset = pausetime
 }

@IBAction func tapResume() {
   let pausedTime = shape.timeOffset
   shape.speed = 1.0
   shape.timeOffset = 0.0
   shape.beginTime = 0.0

   let timeSincePause = shape.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), from: nil) - pausetime
   shape.beginTime = timeSincePause
 }
```

Which methods should I research to get this done?

Comment: UIViewPropertyAnimator hands you all of that on a silver platter (in iOS 10). Otherwise, you'll need to know about `speed` and `timeOffset`.